# Can't Unwrap Optional.None when using CoreData in Swift

Tags: core-data, swift

Ok so the problem actually occurs once the code bit var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext is run I commented it out to confirm that it was that line and it was please note this is my first time learning iOS programming so please try to be as specific as possible in your answer thank you :)

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var txtName : UITextField
@IBOutlet var txtDesc : UITextField
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!)  {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

@IBAction func hitAdd(sender : UIButton) {
    glTask.newTask(txtName.text, desc: txtDesc.text)
    txtName.text = ""
    txtDesc.text = ""
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
    var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
```

> **Right here** V

```
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
```

> **This crashes the app once button is pressed** ^
>
> > **The code error message is** *fatal error Cant unwrap Optional.None*

```
    var newTask = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Tasks", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
    newTask.setValue("test task", forKey: "myTask")
    newTask.setValue("test Description", forKey: "myDesc")
    context.save(nil)
    //println(newTask)
    println("Task was saved.")

}

// UITextField Delegate
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure your application delegate is of type `AppDelegate`? To me, it looks like the `as` cast fails and returns a nil.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean the appDelegate.swift file is generated by Xcode upon making a new project

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the Core Data stack in Swift, `managedObjectContext` is implemented like this:

```
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
    if !_managedObjectContext {
        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        if coordinator != nil {
            _managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
            _managedObjectContext!.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        }
    }
    return _managedObjectContext!
}
var _managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil
```

As you can see it is backed by an Optional.

The place where this can go wrong is here:

```
  _managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
  _managedObjectContext!.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
```

if `NSManagedObjectContext()` returns a `nil`, then the backing `_managedObjectContext` will be nil and you will get this crash at the line where you unwrap it `return _managedObjectContext!`

To debug this, dig deeper down the stack, its most likely failing to initialize the object model or persistant store, and thus returning `nil` to you.

**Edit**:
In the definiton of the getter for `var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`

They provide a location (the wall of comments) where you should debug this exact type of issue.

Comment: I am actually getting an error at return _managedObjectModel! thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode 0x0) my question how would i go about fixing this?

Comment: Yes, the error manifests itself at that point but that is because a `nil` was assigned to _managedObjectModel earlier on

Comment: ok so what should I assign it then? an ! so it will then expect a value later point in the code?

Comment: var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel {
    if !_managedObjectModel {
        let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("core_data", withExtension: "momd")
        _managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)
        }
        return _managedObjectModel!
    }
    var _managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel? = nil

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if OP ever figured this out, but I had a similar issue and realized that the code I copied from another app's `AppDelegate` was using the project name of that app and that I had forgot to change this line: `let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("CoreData", withExtension: "momd")` to use "CoreData" instead of the "test" it had from another project.

Comment: I haven't figured it out quite yet sadly and yes I did change that line